# Replicating data between Postgres DBs

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a Postgres DB that is used by a chat application. The chat system often truncates these tables when they grow to big but I need this data copied to another Postgres database. I will not be truncating the tables in this DB.

How I can configure a few tables on the chat-system's database to replicate data to another Postgres database. Is there a quick way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you consider partitioning the table? And why do you need to copy it to another DB? Wouldn't a different Schema be enough?

Comment: Perhaps you could use dblink and an AFTER INSERT-trigger?

Answer (score 2):

- [`Slony`](http://slony.info/) can replicate only select tables, but I'm not sure how it handles truncates, and it can be a pain to configure.
- You might also use something like [`pgpool`](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) to send copies of the insert statements to a second database.
- You might modify the source of your chat application to do two writes (one to each db) when a new record is created.
- You could just write a script in Perl/PHP/Python to read from one and write to another, then fire it by cron so that you're sure it gets run before truncation.

Answer (score 1):

If you only copy a batch of rows every other day, you may be better off with a plain `INSERT` to a different schema in the same database or a different database in the same database cluster (you need something like [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) for that).

The safest / fastest solution in the same database would be a [data-modifying  CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Something along these lines:

```sql
WITH del AS (
    DELETE FROM tbl
    WHERE  <some condition>
    RETURNING *
    )
INSERT INTO backup.tbl
SELECT * FROM del;
```

For *true* replication consider these official sources:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html